# How can i use Yii widgets and forms?

Tags: php, yii

How can we use a CMultiFileUpload widget and a form that when user clicks the submit button, all files uploaded?

view:

```
<?php
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'CActiveForm',
    array(
        'id' => 'upload-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    )
);

$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
    'name' => 'up_files',
    'attribute' => 'files',
    'model' => $model,
    'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png', // useful for verifying files
    'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', // useful, i think
    'denied' => 'Invalid file type', // useful, i think
));

echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit');
$this->endWidget();
?>
```

model:

```
<?php
class Upload extends CFormModel
{
    public $file;
    //public $file1;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['file', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg'],
        ];
    }
}
```

controller:

```
<?php
class UploadController extends Controller
{
    function actionIndex()
    {
        $dir = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');
        $uploaded = false;

        $model=new Upload();

        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
            //foreach($models as $i=>$model)
            //
            //$files = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('file');
            //print_r($model);
            print_r($model);
            //print_r($files);
            /*if($file->validate()){
                $file->file->saveAs($dir.'/'.$file->file->getName());*/
        }else {
            echo 'Error';
        }


            /*$model->attributes=$_POST['Upload'];
            //print_r($files);
            $model->file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
            //$model->file1 = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
            //print_r($model->file);

            if($model->validate()){
                    $model->file->saveAs($dir.'/'.$model->file->getName());
            }*/

      $this->render('index', array(
            //'files' => $files,
            'model' => $model,
            //'uploaded' => $uploaded,
            //'dir' => $dir,
       ));
    }
}
```

I try this code but not working.
how can I use forms and widgets in yii?

Comment: Please paste your code so far tried

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: when i click Submit button, nothing happen, just that!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you're doing some mistakes:

- At view, remove the `name` attribute/parameter, it is used when you're not using Yii model, just pure HTML.
- At the controller, you're now checking that data is being sent and adding the POST information to the model so you can work with it.

So change it to something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Upload'])) { //model POST
  $model->attributes=$_POST['Upload'];
  print_r($model); //Check the data and do whatever you want
```

- Finally, set the file attribute as safe or required so it can be assigned to the model.

Like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['file', 'safe'],
        ['file', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg'],
    ];
}
```

I recommend you to follow the [Yii basic guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/) so you can understand how this framework works.

Comment: thank you, but $_POST['Upload'] is empty, and this codes still not working

Comment: Check why $_POST is empty, check field names, etc.

Comment: Thank you again, when i use a activeFileField, $_POST not empty, but when i use this widget $_POST isn't isset. why? i don't know really

Comment: Could you update the question to the new code? And tell me what's the content of the "name" attribute of the file upload at the generated html code

Comment: On this code, After i click submit button, $_FILES['up_files'] isn't empty and i can use print_r for show its content, the problem is that isset($_POST['Submit']) returns false

Comment: this is wrong, that's not how yii works, you need to check the POST for the model, no for the button.

Comment: I don't know how use a widget in this form that when submitted, the POST contains the model attributes.

Comment: Did my solution worked? If so, select it as the answer

Comment: No, didn't work, when the form is submitted, $_POST is empty.